# How would I return all the information from the row?

Tags: sql

I have a table with managers and the employees they manage as well as fName, lName etc. I need to count the number of employees a manager manages and return the maximum as well as all the rest of the information in the row.

> > SELECT TOP 1 Manager, COUNT (Manager) AS Manager_Count
> > FROM EMPLOYEE
> > GROUP BY Manager
> > ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

This is what I have but only returns the manager and the count. I have tried adding nested SELECT as well as SELECT * but just keep getting errors. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What errors do you get exactly ? What is your SQL server ?

Comment: SQLQuery and the most common error I've had is columns being invalid as they aren't in   either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. I tried looking that error up but still wasn't able to get the result i need.

Comment: It is difficult to answer precisely without knowing your schema, but the idea behind your errors is that you cannot both group your data, and have single row (non grouped ) data returned in the same query, because SQL cannot guess which row it should get the data from (since they are grouped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about wanting all information for a given manager and the count of employees that manager has, I would suspect the manager is an employee, but also the manager is also a column per employees they are responsible for, such as:

| EmployeeId | Name | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mary | 0 |
| 2 | Joe | 1 |
| 3 | Jane | 1 |
| 4 | Bob | 2 |

Where Mary is the top-level manager and has two direct employees, but Joe is also a manager with one person under him.  So your base query is correct

```
select top 1
      e.Manager,
      count(*) NumberOfEmployees
   from
      Employee e
   group by 
      e.Manager
   order by
      count(*) desc
```

So this gives you the manager's employee ID and the count.  Now, from this aggregated result, join back to the employee table for the manager's direct details.

```
select
      e2.*,
      Mgr.NumberOfEmployees
   from
      ( select top 1
              e.Manager,
              count(*) NumberOfEmployees
           from
              Employee e
           group by 
              e.Manager
           order by
              count(*) desc ) Mgr
         Join Employee e2
            on Mgr.Manager = e2.EmployeeId
```